# Android ProgressDialog won't show in my AsyncTask

Tags: android, dialog, android-asynctask, android-dialog

this is my code.
I have been googling for about 2 hours now and i'm going crazy..
I've been doing exactly like all the examples on websites, but it just won't show, and does not give me any errors.

I'm trying to retrieve a website source in an asyncTask, I want to show the dialog screen, and dismiss it when done.

This is my code:

```
public static class RetrieveSiteData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private Context SubContext;
    private ProgressDialog pd;

    public RetrieveSiteData(Context SubContext){
        this.SubContext = SubContext;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pd = new ProgressDialog(this.SubContext);
        pd.setTitle("Loading. Please wait...");
        pd.show();
        Log.v("Test","dit is het begin");
    } 


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(1000000);


        for (String url : urls) {
            Log.v("URLS",url);
            if(url != "" && url != null){
                try {                   
                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
                    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

                    InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                    String line = null;
                    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        builder.append(line);
                    }
                    in.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }


        return builder.toString();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        pd.dismiss();
        Log.v("Test","dit is het eind");
    }
}
```

Comment: dit is het begin .. is it shown?

Comment: where is your code to call async task like:  `new RetrieveSiteData(SubContext).execute();`

Comment: Your code works for me. Are you sure it's not dismissing it quickly? Are all the log messages getting called? What else do you have going on on screen? Is your context set properly?

Comment: I am executing the code from a fragment, and this still doesn't work. This is the code that calls it: RetrieveSiteData retrieveSiteData = new RetrieveSiteData(getActivity()); String sHtml = retrieveSiteData.execute("myitemsale.co.uk/getMovies.php?q="+sTitle).get();

Comment: I forgot to mention that the logs are showing up! and it takes a good few seconds to load the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try not invoking get() of the AsyncTask. It will block the ui thread until the AsyncTask is done, and thus why the ProgressDialog is not shown.

Comment: I will give that a go, but how will I retrieve the data then? I need to pass this on to the next part of my script.

Comment: Thanks! this works, but how can I retrieve my data from the task?

Comment: onPostExecute() is called with the value you return in doInBackground(), so you can get your data there.

Comment: So if I want to break up that data I would have to do this in the onPostExecute? not in the part where I called the execute?

Comment: If it is time-consuming, you'd better do it in doInBackground(). Since onPreExecute() and onPostExecute() are invoked in ui thread, doing complicated jobs in them will make ANR dialog popup easily.

Answer (score 0):

try to use like that

```
 @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        pd = ProgressDialog.show(SubContext, "", "Loading. Please wait...", true);

        Log.v("Test","dit is het begin");
    }
```

Comment: I am executing the code from a fragment, and this still doesn't work.
This is the code that calls it:

      RetrieveSiteData retrieveSiteData = new RetrieveSiteData(getActivity());
      String sHtml = retrieveSiteData.execute("http://www.myitemsale.co.uk/getMovies.php?q="+sTitle).get();

Comment: what's wrong with OP's code?

Comment: Do you mean sunil? I tried the code but it does the exact same as what I already had. It doesn't show me the dialog.
Is it possible this is because I work with tabs? that for some reason it is showing up in the wrong screen?

Answer (score 0):

just put your activity name

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    pd = new ProgressDialog(Youractivityname.this);
    pd.setTitle("Loading. Please wait...");
    pd.show();
    Log.v("Test","dit is het begin");
}
```